# How To Prevent Internet Explorer Security Alert During HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, security, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate, mshtml

Is there a way to prevent an error message or of programmatically clicking yes to the message that pops up while retrieving an HTTPWebRequest?  The code shown below causes an alert message whose text is "This page has an unspecified potential security risk.  Would you like to continue?"  The caption of the message is "Internet Explorer". Some clues as to what might be causing the error message are:

•   It does not seem to be caused by an sslPolicyErrors as the line of code ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true); should prevent this.

•   Internet Explorer options were set so that the website http://jobsearch.monster.com is on the list of trusted sites.

•   The message occurs after the next to the last line of code is executed:  -oDoc.close();

•   The message can be observed by running the code in response to a button click on a widows form.

•   The error message has to be manually clicked three times (yes or no) in order for the message to dissappear.

•   This is the only web site to date that causes this error message.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using mshtml;

namespace FitCShp
{
    public partial class frmThreadIssue : Form
    {
        public frmThreadIssue()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HTMLDocumentClass oDoc;
            oDoc = GetDoc();
        }

        public HTMLDocumentClass GetDoc()
        {
            string WebAddrs = "http://jobsearch.monster.com/PowerSearch.aspx?q=proven%20record%20relationship&where=portland%2C%20or&rad=20&rad_units=miles&tm=60";
            IHTMLDocument2 oDoc = null;
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebAddrs); //build the request
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true); 
            Req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Req.KeepAlive = false;
            Req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'";
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse();
            //Get the encoding of the response
            System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Enc);  //Create the stream reader
            string sDoc = sr.ReadToEnd();      //read the stream that represents the Webdoc
            sr.Close();                         //close the stream  
            HTMLDocument ProfileHTML = new HTMLDocument();
            oDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)ProfileHTML;
            oDoc.write(sDoc);
            oDoc.close();       //--- Error occurs here
            return (HTMLDocumentClass)oDoc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if your site is trusted, the settings for that security level can be changed to be very restrictive...

Answer (score 2):

If your page is running in the HTTPS context, but is referencing elements from other sites via HTTP, you'll get this security warning.  Make sure that all referenced content (e.g. images, style sheets, etc) are referenced with HTTPS in the URL.

Comment: At this point I'm realizing the problem has nothing to do with the HTTPWebRequest as I can save the string that is the result of the HTTPWebRequest (sDoc) as a file without triggering the error message. However, if I open up that file and convert it to an IHTMLDocument2 the error message reappears. So, it looks like the problem is one of preventing the error message that arises from the COM object in the mshtml namespace that converts the string to an IHTMLDocument2 document.

Comment: did you try enabling active content on your computer to run, as I have indicated above?

Comment: feroze:  I did try to to enable the active content. I bascially, enabled every option I could.  However, I still get the message.  Is there a way to remove all security measures from Internet Explorer and test this, to see if will solve the problem.  In another forum someone suggested converting the HTML doucment to XML or XHTML and using the system.xml tools to analyze the page.  I'm concerned about the interchangability of the two systems.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpWebRequest is happening on the server side, not the client, so that is not the cause of your client's warning message. The only way the browser would react like that is if you had non-secure calls on the markup itself.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Crap, didn't notice the Silverlight tag, thanks. I saw the button-click event and figured this was an ASP.NET page, but now I see this is a WinForms form. Apparently I'm not quite up to speed on Silverlight - I didn't realize you used a System.Windows.Forms.Form in a Silverlight app.

Comment: Well, my bad. I haven't noticed the `Windows.Forms`. It's still client-side but instead of Silverlight, it's using `MSHTML`.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Ahh...Now I see what's going on. I've never actually used a WebBrowser control. Mixing Windows forms and the Web always seemed like a bad idea to me.

Comment: The windows form simply provides a means of launching the application.  A webbrowser control isn't used by any code in this part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the object HTMLDocument remove all javascript code, here my VB code:

```
response = Regex.Replace(resp, "<script.*?</script>", String.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the security settings under Tools->InternetOptions->Advanced->Security. For eg "Allow active content from files in my computer to run.."

Comment: feroze: I did try to to enable the active content. I bascially, enabled every option I could. However, I still get the message. Is there a way to remove all security measures from Internet Explorer and test this, to see if will solve the problem. In another forum someone suggested converting the HTML doucment to XML or XHTML and using the system.xml tools to analyze the page. I'm concerned about the interchangability of the two systems.